# jQuery fullCalendar showing events on top of parent elements

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

This is a question regarding to [fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar).

What I'm trying to do is to show the portions of the events that are covered by the edges of the calendar.
Here is a picture to help you understand easier. [image]
I'm trying to get the portion of event (indicated by the dashed lines) showing on top of the edge of the calendar.

Modifying the z-indexes of the events didn't help.
Anyone know how I can make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your container have an overflow:hidden? It would be easier if you gave us the link to your site or at least the css and html part used to do that

Comment: You're right! I made another thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765935/full-calendar-css-displaying-events-outside-the-calendar-canvas/12765948#12765948, and someone answered it for me. I guess it all came down to asking the right question.

Comment: You could posted the link here as well. no need for double posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made another thread with a different way of asking the same question. Someone answered it for me at: [Full Calendar CSS - displaying events outside the calendar canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765935/full-calendar-css-displaying-events-outside-the-calendar-canvas/12765948#12765948)