# Full Calendar CSS - displaying events outside the calendar canvas

Tags: css, fullcalendar

If you take a look at fullCalendar website, we are presented with a calendar.

If I attempt to drag the calendar's event, the events are always hidden behind the canvas' edges [image: hidden behind the canvas' edges]

Is there any way I can modify the CSS, so the events are popped up outside of the canvas? [image: popped up outside of the canvas?]

The calendar can be found here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
div.fc-view.fc-view-month.fc-grid {
  overflow: visible;
}
```